# failure to install packages in RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am a bit new to RStudio, I had the previous version but I uninstalled it to install the latest version but when I try to install any package (I try to install tidyverse as an example) it does not install and what appears is the following:

```
    Installing package into ‘/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    also installing the dependencies ‘broom’, ‘haven’, ‘modelr’, ‘readr’, ‘feather’, ‘testthat’
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/broom_0.7.9.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 631606 bytes (616 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 616 KB
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/haven_2.4.3.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 296805 bytes (289 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 289 KB
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.8.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121333 bytes (118 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 118 KB
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/readr_2.0.1.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 517944 bytes (505 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 505 KB
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/feather_0.3.5.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 73812 bytes (72 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 72 KB
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/testthat_3.0.4.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 688142 bytes (672 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 672 KB
    
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.1.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 702779 bytes (686 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 686 KB
    
    * installing *source* package ‘broom’ ...
    ** package ‘broom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** using staged installation
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    *** copying figures
    ** building package indices
    ** installing vignettes
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
    ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
    * DONE (broom)
    ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ for modifying
    Try removing ‘/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-readr’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status
    * installing *source* package ‘feather’ ...
    ** package ‘feather’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** using staged installation
    Platform is little endian. Good.
    ** libs
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather-read.cpp -o feather-read.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather-types.cpp -o feather-types.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather-write.cpp -o feather-write.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/buffer.cc -o feather/buffer.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/feather-c.cc -o feather/feather-c.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/io.cc -o feather/io.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/metadata.cc -o feather/metadata.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/reader.cc -o feather/reader.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/status.cc -o feather/status.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/types.cc -o feather/types.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I'/home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c feather/writer.cc -o feather/writer.o
    ar rcs libfeather.a feather/buffer.o feather/feather-c.o feather/io.o feather/metadata.o feather/reader.o feather/status.o feather/types.o feather/writer.o
    g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o feather.so RcppExports.o feather-read.o feather-types.o feather-write.o -L. -lfeather -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
    installing to /home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-feather/00new/feather/libs
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
    ** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
    ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
    * DONE (feather)
    * installing *source* package ‘testthat’ ...
    ** package ‘testthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** using staged installation
    ** libs
    gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
    gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c reassign.c -o reassign.o
    g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test-catch.cpp -o test-catch.o
    g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test-example.cpp -o test-example.o
    g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-QwogzP/r-base-4.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test-runner.cpp -o test-runner.o
    g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o testthat.so init.o reassign.o test-catch.o test-example.o test-runner.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-testthat/00new/testthat/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

This repeats for an indefinite period of time which I have to stop it but it never installs the package, I am on Ubuntu 20.04 operating system.

Comment: Try ``rm -rf /home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-readr`` and trying again.

Comment: After executing the command `rm -rf /home/edgardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-readr` I downloaded the whole package, thank you very much.